# Down votes for no apparent reason

Tags: discussion

Not that I lose sleep over stuff like this, but I have always been baffled when I notice I have a random -2 due to a down vote, that I just cant understand the reasoning for.  I received one this morning, and took a look

[Apex cron job command to schedule an apex job to run every 4 hours daily](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16841/apex-cron-job-command-to-schedule-an-apex-job-to-run-every-4-hours-daily)

Randomly, this morning, I received a down vote on my answer.  I just don't understand why.

[image]

I don't down vote very often, but when I do, as a rule I always try to comment as to the reason.  I have always thought that you should be required to comment if you down vote.  I know this may cause issues as it might give away the identity of the down voter, but perhaps the site could make it an anonymous comment, I don't know, just brainstorming here, but at least you could have some insight as to what the reason is.

Is the answer I gave incorrect or lacking sufficient explanation?  Just something that has always bugged me a bit when I get a down vote and cannot figure out why.

I have no issue with a down vote if I give an answer that is incorrect, or shows little effort, or I'm just regurgitating documentation, but its tough when you just can't figure out the reason for the down vote.

Comment: I see a lot of questions receiving downvotes without much of an explanation. We can't expect everyone to know from the start how stackexchange works.

Comment: I'd like to down vote for blatant cribbing of an already posted answer only this time complete with a pretty screnshot. Great value add </sarcasm> . No prizes for guessing which answer was NOT selected.

Comment: ?????????????????  I guess I don't understand the aggression.  I dont understand the comment either.

Comment: Not directed at you sir or this specific question.  I'm new here, still learning the ropes so perhaps the behaviour I refer to is covered in a FAQ somewhere. Just an observation in my short time here. In short, I chose to vent rather than down vote . My apologies for the aggressive tone or hijacking your answer

Comment: Oh... I actually get it now.  I thought you were directing it at the question here or the answer I was alluding to.  I see what you were doing now.  Yes though, I agree with your frustration at certain answers

Comment: Was looking back through old questions and saw this. I just earned the Gold "unsung hero" badge (zero vote accepted answers, more than 25% of total) in part because of downvotes like you describe. LOL! Hidden reward perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

Nothing appears wrong or bad about your answer, so I think one of two things:

The optimist in me:  It was accidental.

The pessimist in me:  Somebody is a ********.

Comment: haha....well that made me laugh, so I'm good.  Just glad I wasn't crazy to wonder what it was for.